# Global verification Function not working

Tags: jmeter

I tried global Response Assertion like when you get text "Error" in Response it should fail that response. but it is not working. Could you please give how to over come the issue.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're using incorrect value in `Apply to` field, you're getting this `ERROR` in a [Sub-Result](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getSubResults--) while Assertion is checking only top-level [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)(s)

You need to tick `Main sample and sub-samples` box in order to apply the assertion to Sub-Results as well:

[image]

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps/)

Comment: Thank you it is working now. It is working by selecting "Contains" under "Pattern matching rules"

Comment: Convert your comment to answer and accept it as a solution.